# Jolt transforming to array

Tags: json, jolt

I am getting null in my output json. Please find my spec and details below. The input json can have n numbers of COMPINFO . pls suggest

my input.json is

```
{
    "valid": "true",
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "COMPINFO": [
            {
                "ORGID": "",
                "SITEID": "BWDEMO",
                "COMPID": "C2014",
                "COMP_DESC": "Cherokee High School",
                "ASSETTYPE": "MANUFACTURING",
                "BUILDING": "Main",
                "FLR_LEVEL": "Ground",
                "ROOM_SPCE": "100"
            },
            {
                "ORGID": "",
                "SITEID": "BWDEMO",
                "COMPID": "9001B",
                "COMP_DESC": "Sludge Pump",
                "ASSETTYPE": "FACILITY",
                "BUILDING": "Main",
                "FLR_LEVEL": "Production",
                "ROOM_SPCE": "100"  
            } 
        ]
    }
}
```

my Spec.json is

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "COMPINFO": {
          "*": {
            "COMPID": "[&1].COMPID",
            "ORGID": "[&1].ORGID",
            "COMP_DESC": "[&1].DESCRIPTION",
            "BUILDING": "[&1].LOCATIONS.[&1].Building",
            "FLR_LEVEL": "[&1].LOCATIONS.[&1].Floor_Level",
            "ROOM_SPCE": "[&1].LOCATIONS.[&1].ROOM_SPCE",
            "SITEID": "[&1].SITEID",
            "ASSETTYPE": "[&1].ASSETTYPE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

expected output should be :

```
    [ 
     {
      "COMPID" : "C2014",
      "ORGID" : "",
      "DESCRIPTION" : "Cherokee High School",
      "LOCATIONS" : [ {
        "Building" : "Main",
        "Floor_Level" : "Ground",
        "ROOM_SPCE" : "100"
      } ],
      "SITEID" : "BWDEMO",
      "ASSETTYPE" : "MANUFACTURING"
    }, {
      "COMPID" : "9001B",
      "ORGID" : "",
      "DESCRIPTION" : "Sludge Pump",
      "LOCATIONS" : [{
        "Building" : "Main",
        "Floor_Level" : "Production",
        "ROOM_SPCE" : "100"
      } ],
      "SITEID" : "BWDEMO",
      "ASSETTYPE" : "FACILITY"
    } 
]
```

but getting null (highlighted (Bold)) :

```
[ 
{
  "COMPID" : "C2014",
  "ORGID" : "",
  "DESCRIPTION" : "Cherokee High School",
  "LOCATIONS" : [ {
    "Building" : "Main",
    "Floor_Level" : "Ground",
    "ROOM_SPCE" : "100"
  } ],
  "SITEID" : "BWDEMO",
  "ASSETTYPE" : "MANUFACTURING"
}, {
  "COMPID" : "9001B",
  "ORGID" : "",
  "DESCRIPTION" : "Sludge Pump",
  "LOCATIONS" : [ null, {
    "Building" : "Main",
    "Floor_Level" : "Production",
    "ROOM_SPCE" : "100"
  } ],
  "SITEID" : "BWDEMO",
  "ASSETTYPE" : "FACILITY"
} 
]
```

can someone help quickly ??

Thanks in advance .ssssssssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you there is only one "location" per input item, and that you just want them to alway be the first element in a location array.

If so that is easy.   If you are wanting to "group" your data and have some of the locations array have multiple items, that is a harder transform.

Spec for the simple version

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "COMPINFO": {
          "*": {
            "COMPID": "[&1].COMPID",
            "ORGID": "[&1].ORGID",
            "COMP_DESC": "[&1].DESCRIPTION",
            "BUILDING": "[&1].LOCATIONS[0].Building",
            "FLR_LEVEL": "[&1].LOCATIONS[0].Floor_Level",
            "ROOM_SPCE": "[&1].LOCATIONS[0].ROOM_SPCE",
            "SITEID": "[&1].SITEID",
            "ASSETTYPE": "[&1].ASSETTYPE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

There are examples around for the harder version.